# Use regex to remove "public://" from string

Tags: javascript, regex

Im lost in part of this.

I want to remove the `public://` in every link of an image like `public://china-taxi_4.jpg`

I have tried this but returns null:

```
 var _img = 'public://china-taxi_4.jpg';
 var regex = /(public:)(\/\w+)/;

 var matches = _img.match(regex);
 console.log(matches);
```

Hope you can help.

Comment: Do you want `_img = _img.replace(/^public\:\/\//,'')` ?

Comment: Can't a replace method do this?

Comment: Why not using String Replace function

Comment: @Paul Wait. Did you see the comment which came long before the answers ?

Comment: @dystroy No I didn't notice your comment. Sorry.  Marked my answer community wiki.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to remove the 'public://' in every link of an image.

```
> var img = 'public://china-taxi_4.jpg';
> img.replace(/public:\/\/(?=\S+?\.jpg(?:\s|$))/, "")
'china-taxi_4.jpg'
```

It removes the word `public://` only in the strings which ends with `.jpg`

Answer (score -1):

You are removing a literal string, not a regular expression. So try:

```
var _img = 'public://china-taxi_4.jpg';

var result = _img.replace("public://","");
console.log(result);
```

Regexes are for matching complex expressions.

Answer (score -1):

```
var re = /(public:)(\/\/[\w-.]+)/g;
```

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/rA7aS3/9

Comment: Thanks everyone. 
yes, that can be solved with replace function but, I want it with regex for some practice also.

Comment: @user3528843 try now the New re for matching

Answer (score -1):

I think you're missing a slash, try:

```
var _img = 'public://china-taxi_4.jpg';
var regex = /(public:)(\/\/\w+)/;

var matches = _img.match(regex);
console.log(matches);
```

Answer (score -1):

From Mozilla Developer Network [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

> Example: Defining the regular expression in replace()
>
> In the following example, the regular expression is defined in
>   replace() and includes the ignore case flag.
>
> ```
>  var str = 'Twas the night before Xmas...'; 
>  var newstr = str.replace(/xmas/i, 'Christmas'); 
>  console.log(newstr);
> ```
>
> This prints:
>
> 'Twas the night before Christmas...'

To match the beginning of a string, use `^`

To escape characters that have special meaning in regexp like `:` and `/` so that regexp will match these literally, prepend `\`

This suggests:

```
var _img = 'public://china-taxi_4.jpg';
var newimg = _img.replace(/^public\:\/\//i, '');
```

Tested and working in chrome browser console window.

Note:  This answer also matches an earlier comment by @dystroy, so I have marked it CW.